# What does the "synchronization policy" mean when launching a kernel?

Tags: cuda, synchronization, cuda-streams, cuda-driver

Starting with CUDA 12.0, one can specify a wider variety of "launch attributes", when launching a kernel, using a [CUlaunchConfig](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/structCUlaunchConfig.html#structCUlaunchConfig) structure; and one of the attributes we can place in a launch config structure is a "synchronization policy".

Now, CUDA *streams* have had synchronization policies for a long time. That policy can be "auto", "spin", "yield", "block" (which you can read about in the documentation, and are not extremely well described, but never mind). But - how do these apply to a kernel launch?

---

<sub>see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77896717/1593077) regarding another mysterious field of the kernel launch config structure.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on [this section of the CUDA driver API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__TYPES.html#group__CUDA__TYPES_1gg6f6565b334be6bb3134868e10bbdd33176a390a5743b2f72d392a429d413f64f:%7E:text=Valid%20for%20streams.%20See%20CUlaunchAttributeValue%3A%3AsyncPolicy.), the `CU_LAUNCH_ATTRIBUTE_SYNCHRONIZATION_POLICY` attribute is not valid for launches:

> Valid for streams. See `CUlaunchAttributeValue::syncPolicy`.

Comment: But these are _kernel_ launch attributes. You can't launch streams.

Comment: These are extensible launch attributes, so applying it so a stream means they will apply to all kernel launches within that stream. As mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/77916813/11420748, launch-level attributes have precedence over stream-level attributes.

Comment: In case that helps:
`$ grep CUstreamAttrID /usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h | grep typedef`
returns `typedef CUlaunchAttributeID CUstreamAttrID;`