# What are the semantics of CUDA kernel launch priorities?

Tags: cuda, cuda-streams, cuda-driver

Starting with CUDA 12.0, one can specify a wider variety of "launch attributes", when launching a kernel, using a [CUlaunchConfig](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/structCUlaunchConfig.html#structCUlaunchConfig) structure; and one of the attributes we can place in a launch config structure is a "launch priority".

Now, CUDA *streams* have had a scheduling priority for a long time; they are described in [§ 3.2.8.5.7 of the CUDA Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#stream-priorities); and you can obtain the range of possible priorities with [`cuCtxGetStreamPriorityRange()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g137920ab61a71be6ce67605b9f294091). But what are *kernel* launch priorities? Are they an override of the stream's priority, when the kernel is the next task  to schedule? Are they a modifier of the stream's priority? Something else?

---

<sub>See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77896633/1593077) regarding another mysterious field of the kernel launch config structure.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Are they an override of the stream's priority

Yes, it does override the stream priority. Launch-level attributes have precedence over stream-level attributes.

Comment: This was flagged internally to make sure we do document this behavior from now on. I will update my answer once that is done. Thanks!